# Get all values from child elements of a dict as a list

Tags: python

```
T = {'a': {'c': 'A', 'path': '/c'}, 'e': {'c': 'E', 'path': '/e'}, 's': {'c': 'S', 'path': '/s'}}
```

I need all 'path' elements as a list. I know I can iterate through everything in a single for, but I would like to know other *pythonic* ways of extracting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think that there is no way except iterate so you can use the following code:

```
[v['path'] for k,v in T.iteritems() if k in <top level keys to be used>]
```

EDITED as per comments: I have used iteritems since it allows you to perform filter action using top level keys if neccessary, otherwise(if you don't care about top level keys) it is better to use @phant0m's solution with itervalues.

```
[v['path'] for v in T.itervalues() if k in <top level keys to be used>]
```

OR [dict.get](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict.get#dict.get):

```
[v.get('path') for v in T.itervalues()]
```

OR, just for completeness, not so fast but using map and lambda:

```
from operator import itemgetter
map(itemgetter('path'), T.itervalues())
```

Comment: @Somebody: Just note that the 3rd method is probably just here for completeness' sake. It's not appropriate for real-world use.

Comment: The third should just use `operator.itemgetter('path')`. Then it's also appropriate if the rest of the program is written in a somewhat functional style, and propably doesn't suffer the full performance penalty.

Comment: @delnan could you please give me a line with itemgetter - just for me - because i have tried but i was not able to use it.

Comment: `map(operator.itemgetter("path"), T.itervalues())`

Comment: `import operator; print map(operator.itemgetter('path'), T.itervalues())`. Just noticed that you're needlessly using `iteritems` where you only need its second part, the value - *all* the ways should be using `itervalues`...

Comment: I would prefer `for v in T.itervalues()` to `for k,v in T.iteritems()`.

Comment: Yes - i see - thank you, i just used iteritems since i am usually using dictionary keys to filter top level data

Answer (score 4):

Or simpler:

```
>>> [x["path"] for x in T.itervalues()]
['/c', '/s', '/e']
```