# Switching From Lists to JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently have a script that uses a number of lists as lookups which have a structure like so:

people.py

```
roster = ['Bob','Alice','Trent','Eve','Mallory','Chad','Victor','Grace']
```

roles.py

```
ClassA = ['Bob','Alice','Trent','Eve']
ClassB = ['Bob','Mallory','Chad','Victor','Grace']
```

portraits.py

```
portrait = {
'bob':'bob.png',
'alice':'alice.png',
'trent':'trent.png',
'eve':'eve.png',
'mallory':'mallory.png',
'chad':'chad.png',
'victor':'victor.png',
'grace':'grace.png'
}
```

main.py

```
import people
import roles
import portraits

classes=['ClassA','ClassB']

names = people.roster
for name in names:
    
    n = name.replace("-", "").replace("'", "").replace(".", "").replace(" ", "").lower()
    picture = portraits.portrait[n]

for p in classes:
    rslt = getattr(roles, p)
    #more operations here, e.g. a dataframe filter: df = df[df['name'].isin(rslt)]
```

I would like to move all of this into a uniform data structure like this as it would be easier to maintain:

persons.json

```
{
   "title":"person-schema",
   "revdate":"02-21-2022",
   "data":[
      {
         "name":"Bob",
         "uid":"bob",
         "id":"s001",
         "portrait":"bob.png",
         "classes": ["ClassA","ClassB"],
         "attributes":[
            {
             
            }]
      },
      {
         "name":"Alice",
         "uid":"alice",
         "id":"s002",
         "portrait":"alice.png",
         "classes": ["ClassA"],
         "attributes":[
            {
             
            }]
      },
      {
         "name":"Mallory",
         "uid":"mallory",
         "id":"s003",
         "portrait":"mallory.png",
         "classes": ["ClassB"],
         "attributes":[
            {
             
            }]
      }

    ]
}
```

I know this is a loaded question, but how would I go about rewriting these lookups?

- people.roster >> ?
- getattr(roles, p) >> ?
- portraits.portrait[n] >>?

Comment: Very important to understand, that is not JSON. JSON is a text-based serialization format.

Comment: `list` is a list constructor. Do not use it as a variable name.

Comment: I would like each person record to be an object with their own key-value pairs, whatever those might be. If not JSON, what is it?
per https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Fixed variable name.

Comment: It's a dictionary. If you write it to a file, that file could be in JSON format. But you could also use Pickle.

Comment: Is there a specific need to have 3 separate files? All your objects could already be in one file, or you could _start_ with them in JSON and load them when the code runs

Comment: No, there is no need to have 3 separate files.
Historically, the script was created in parts and there is some duplication of effort here.

Right now, I have consolidated all of the individual lists into a JSON-formatted "master lookup" file, but I am sort of at a loss as to how to access the data there.

Answer (score 2):

I would loop through your roster once, doing the necessary matches foreach.  For each name, initiate an empty dict, then fill relevant elements.

Something like...

```
#initiate empty array to hold data
persons_data = []

for name in name:
   person_data = {
      "name": name
      ,"portrait": "{}.png".format(lower(name))  #assumes all persons have photo and standard naming convention
      ,"classes": []
   }

   #assumes standard, unique names across both datasets
   if name in ClassA:
      person_data["classes"].append('ClassA')
   if name in ClassB:
      person_data["classes"].append('ClassB')

   persons_data.append(person_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short helper function to quickly json-ify your data:

```py
    from typing import *
    from math import log10, floor
    import portraits, roles, people


    NEXT_ID: Int = 0

    def student_to_json(name: str, attrs: List[Dict[Any, Any]] = [{}])-> Dict[str, Any]:
        name = name.strip().replace("-", "").replace("'", "").replace(".", "").replace(" ", "").lower()
        if name is None or not word.isalpha() or not word.isascii(): return "" # invalid name
        NEXT_ID += 1
        return {
                "name": name.title(),
                "uid": name,
                "id": f"s{'0' * (3 - floor(log10(NEXT_ID)) + 1)}{NEXT_ID - 1}"
                "portrait": portraits.portrait.get(name, "blank_avatar.png") # include a default image,
                "classes": [c[1] if name.title in c[0] for c in [(roles.ClassA, "ClassA"), (roles.ClassB, "ClassB")]]
                "attributes": attrs
           }
```

You could then call this like

```py
   import json
   import datetime
   from datetime import datetime as dt

   # import attributes ??
   # attributes.data[person_name] = [{"eye-color": "blue", ...}, ...]

    with open(f'people-schema.json', 'w+') as fptr:
        data = [student_to_json(p, attributes.data.get(p, [{}])) for p in people.roster]
        json.dumps({"revdate": dt.now(), "data": data}, fptr) # add attributes as necessary
```

Everything should then be outputted to a new file called `people-schema.json`.

(Added support for students enrolled in more than one class, per @ScottieB's comment)

Comment: This is great for creating the data file.
*I already have the data file created, but your suggestion is very helpful.

Comment: Great answer, quick note that Persons can be in multiple Classes

Comment: @p3hndrx - Glad you liked it! If you feel it answered your question, please hit the green checkmark to accept it as the official answer to help future SO users with similar questions. Also thanks `ScottieB` for the advice, I added support for that per your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The persons.json file exists.

I can bring it in using something like:

```
 jsonfile = 'persons.json'
 with open(jsonfile) as j:
    data = json.load(j)
```

For clarification of the ask:

Old method for referencing the list:
`names = people.roster`

New method?
`names = [x["name"] for x in data.itervalues()]`
?

Reference:
[Get all values from child elements of a dict as a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651194/get-all-values-from-child-elements-of-a-dict-as-a-list)